# Unable to find and Delete a row using a string value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and delete a row containing a specific value. For this, I use the following excel-VBA code but it shows an error and hence finds nothing (shows rfnd=nothing).
My code is -

```
Sub Save_Data_on_Master_Sheet()
'''' Save Data on Master Sheet''''
Dim Str As String, rfnd As Range

Str = Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("P2")

Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("D5:D2000").Select
Set rfnd = Selection.Find(Str, After:=Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("D4"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
rfnd.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Links of screenshots
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v0zfs575mjqz7ve/Capture.JPG?dl=0 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3hxrpbcj1pjx7oc/Capture.JPG2.JPG?dl=0

Could anyone tell me where I did make a mistake!

Comment: That means the `Find` didn't find anything in that range... are you sure there's a match?

Comment: Yes, there is a value in cell D6

Comment: Any chance you can share a sample screenshot or add some sample data?

Comment: `Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("D5:D2000").Select`, scratch that, and set a `Range` object. This will throw an error on you the minute `MASTER_DATA` isn't the `ActiveSheet`. As per weather or not you should find a match, inspect your data and make sure there are no leading/trailing spaces throwing off `Range.Find`

Comment: Don't know how to add photo in a comment.

Comment: You can [edit] your original question.

Comment: I think your `After` cell should be in the range being searched.

Comment: @SJR, yes it should, and should fix the error =)

Comment: MASTER_DATA sheet is an ActiveSheet. In find section, LookIn:=xlValues, shows a value -4163.

Comment: @Abhyudaya - in `After:=Sheets("MASTER_DATA").Range("D4")` - `D4` is *outside* the `Range` being searched ("D5:D2000"). Either change that to a cell inside the range or get rid of the `After` parameter entirely.

Comment: @Abhyudaya - it was SJR and please remember to accept the answer below by clicking the check mark to the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comment, immediate cause of your error was that your `After` parameter was set to be a cell outside the range being searched.

Below I have removed it altogether as in general it's not needed (at least not seemingly in this case).

You can also [avoid Selecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba).

And always check that your `Find` finds something before operating on the result to avoid an error.

```
Sub Save_Data_on_Master_Sheet()

Dim Str As String, rfnd As Range

With Sheets("MASTER_DATA")
    Str = .Range("P2").Value
    Set rfnd = .Range("D5:D2000").Find(Str, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not rfnd Is Nothing Then rfnd.EntireRow.Delete
End With

End Sub
```